# Get a column from the list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples. Is it possible to get a column from each tuple without using numpy, pandas etc?

```
lst = [('a','b','c'),
       ('d','e','f')]
```

Lets say I want to get 'b','e', but with

```
lst[:][1]
```

I get

> ('d', 'e', 'f')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "list comprehension", here is a taste of it that addresses your question:

```py
lst = [('a','b','c'),
       ('d','e','f')]

col1 = [tple[1] for tple in lst]
print(col1)
```

Comment: `list(zip(*lst))[1]` is another interesting, though admittedly less Pythonic, alternative

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map()`:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[1], lst))
```

```
['b', 'e']
```

For all items in your list (i.e., every tuple), it will select the element at index 1.